# Dynamic API routing with getServerSideProps in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to fetch Dynamic API routing after enter submit with input state. but I don't know how to pass state from react to getServerSideProps.

this is my code

```
export default function Home(props) {
    const { data } = props;
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const handlerChange = (event) => {
        setInput(event.target.value);
    };
    const handlerSubmit = () => {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        setInput("");
    };

    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Group Name"
            value={input}
            onChange={handlerChange}
            onKeyDown={(event) =>
                event.key === "Enter" && handlerSubmit(event)
            }
        />
    )

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/searchGroup/${input}`)
    const data = await res.json()
  
    return { props: { data } }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the request with the updated `input` value from the client-side instead inside the `handlerSubmit` callback and save the `data` to be rendered in a state variable (e.g. `dataToRender`).

```js
const getData = async (input) => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/searchGroup/${input}`)
    return res.json()
}

export default function Home(props) {
    const { data } = props;
    const [dataToRender, setDataToRender] = useState(data);
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

    const handlerChange = (event) => {
        setInput(event.target.value);
    };

    const handlerSubmit = async (event) => {
        setInput("");
        const newData = await getData(event.target.value);
        setDataToRender(newData);
    };

    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Group Name"
            value={input}
            onChange={handlerChange}
            onKeyDown={(event) =>
                event.key === "Enter" && handlerSubmit(event)
            }
        />
    )
}
```

---

As an alternative to the above, if you absolutely need to have the request in `getServerSideProps`, then you can pass the `input` value as a query parameter and read it from `context.query.input` in `getServerSideProps`.

```js
// On the client-side
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home(props) {
    const router = useRouter()    

    const handlerSubmit = () => {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        setInput("");
        router.push(`${router.pathname}?input=${event.target.value}`);
    }
    
    // Remaining code...
}
```

```js
// On the server-side
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/searchGroup/${context.query.input ?? 'default-value'}`)
    const data = await res.json()
  
    return { props: { data } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) instead to navigate to something like a `/your-current-page/${input}` and you would then have access to the input value as a param in getServerSideProps as such:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
    const { input } = params;
     
    ...
}
```

More info on this [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter)